# Cant set Variables in Final Builder using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, finalbuilder

I'm trying to use the RunScript Action in Final Builder and I can't seem to make any changes to variables e.g.

function OnExecute(Action, Action)

FBVariables.TestMyVariable = "42"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To be honest it was already working. Just not updating the values in the Watch window! Thanks for your help anyway. I'll vote you accepted answer for your troubles :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using VBScript you can set the FinalBuilder value directly.

`MyTestVariable = "Hello World"`

No need to prefix it with anything.

Answer (score 0):

In a javascript action in FB, you can do this:

FBVariables.MyVariable = true;  // or whatever